# A simple CLI arbitrary-precision Mandelbrot set calculator (for a single point)

Tags: c, console, complex-numbers

I wrote the following C code that takes a couple of arguments on the command line and calculates a given number of iterations of the Mandelbrot set complex mapping using MPFR arbitrary precision arithmetic. Is it well-written? Does it have undefined behaviour or is unsafe?

Here is the code:

**Makefile**

```
CC := gcc
O := 1
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wpedantic -std=gnu17 -O$(O) $(XCFLAGS)
XCFLAGS :=

mpfrtest: mpfrtest.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -lm -lmpfr $^ -o $@

mpfrtest.o: mpfrtest.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f mpfrtest
```

**mpfrtest.c**

```c
#include <complex.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpfr.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ESCAPE_NORM 4
#define ROUND MPFR_RNDN

size_t orbit(const mpfr_t c_re, const mpfr_t c_im, size_t M,
             double complex *output, mpfr_prec_t prec, mpfr_rnd_t round,
             void (*callback)(size_t)) {
    mpfr_t z_re, z_im;
    mpfr_inits2(prec, z_re, z_im, NULL);
    mpfr_set_ui(z_re, 0, round);
    mpfr_set_ui(z_im, 0, round);
    mpfr_t re_tmp, im_tmp;
    mpfr_inits2(prec, re_tmp, im_tmp, NULL);
    double interval_d = ceil(sqrt((double)M));
    size_t interval;
    if (interval_d < 1) {
        interval = 1;
    } else {
        interval = (size_t)interval_d;
    }
    output[0] = 0;
    size_t m = 0;
    for (; m < M && mpfr_cmp_ui(re_tmp, ESCAPE_NORM) <= 0; m++) {
        mpfr_sqr(re_tmp, z_re, round);
        mpfr_sqr(im_tmp, z_im, round);
        mpfr_sub(im_tmp, im_tmp, c_re, round);
        mpfr_sub(re_tmp, re_tmp, im_tmp, round);
        mpfr_mul(z_im, z_re, z_im, round);
        mpfr_mul_ui(z_im, z_im, 2, round);
        mpfr_add(z_im, z_im, c_im, round);
        mpfr_set(z_re, re_tmp, round);
        output[m] = mpfr_get_d(z_re, round) + mpfr_get_d(z_im, round) * I;
        mpfr_sqr(re_tmp, z_re, round);
        mpfr_sqr(im_tmp, z_im, round);
        mpfr_add(re_tmp, re_tmp, im_tmp, round);
        if (m % interval == 0) {
            (*callback)(m);
        }
    }
    mpfr_clears(re_tmp, im_tmp, z_re, z_im, NULL);
    return m;
}

int digitsiz(size_t value) {
    value++;
    int count = 0;
    while (value >= 10) {
        value /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void progress(size_t m) { fprintf(stderr, "computed iteration %zu\n", m); }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 5) {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong argument count %d, should be 4\n", argc - 1);
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "usage: %s <Re[c]> <Im[c]> <precision> <maximum iteration count>\n",
            argv[0]);
        exit(-5);
    }
    char *endptr;
    errno = 0;
    signed long prec_l = strtol(argv[3], &endptr, 10);
    if (argv[3][0] == '\0' || *endptr != '\0') {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to parse argument precision as a number\n");
        exit(-3);
    }
    if (errno == ERANGE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "argument precision is too large\n");
        exit(-3);
    }
    if (prec_l <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "argument precision must be positive\n");
        exit(-3);
    }
    mpfr_prec_t prec = (mpfr_prec_t)prec_l;
    errno = 0;
    uintmax_t iter_umax = strtoumax(argv[4], &endptr, 10);
    if (argv[4][0] == '\0' || *endptr != '\0') {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "failed to parse argument maximum iteration count as a number\n");
        exit(-4);
    }
    if (iter_umax > (uintmax_t)SIZE_MAX || errno == ERANGE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "argument maximum iteration count is too large\n");
        exit(-4);
    }
    size_t iter = (size_t)iter_umax;
    mpfr_t c_re;
    mpfr_t c_im;
    mpfr_inits2(prec, c_re, c_im, NULL);
    if (mpfr_set_str(c_re, argv[1], 10, ROUND) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to parse argument Re[c] as a number\n");
        mpfr_clears(c_re, c_im, NULL);
        exit(-4);
    };
    if (mpfr_set_str(c_im, argv[2], 10, ROUND) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to parse argument Im[c] as a number\n");
        mpfr_clears(c_re, c_im, NULL);
        exit(-5);
    }
    double complex *result = malloc(iter * sizeof(double complex));
    if (result == NULL) {
        perror("orbit array allocation");
        mpfr_clears(c_re, c_im, NULL);
        exit(-6);
    }
    size_t m = orbit(c_re, c_im, iter, result, prec, ROUND, progress);
    if (m == SIZE_MAX) {
        printf("iterations = max");
    } else {
        printf("iterations = %zu\n", m);
    }
    int width = digitsiz(m);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("orbit[%0*zu] = %13.6e + %13.6ei\n", width, i, creal(result[i]),
               cimag(result[i]));
    }
    mpfr_clears(c_re, c_im, NULL);
    free(result);
}
```

Comment: If you have a makefile, include that in your question. If you don't, you should write one.

Comment: What standard of C are you compiling with?

Comment: I use -std=gnu17

Comment: It works with ISO C 17, too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Only for the pedantic**

`strtou...()` functions have a quirk in that `strtoumax("-1", &endptr, 10)` is some large positive value without setting `errno`.

If that is OK, 'nuff said.

If code wants to detect *negative* strings, consider `strtomax()` and test the range.

```
// Demonstrative unchecked code.

// Like strtoumax()`, yet caps negative conversions rather than wrap.
// This does allow "-0" to quietly return 0 with no setting of `errno`.
uintmax_t strtoumax_alt(const char * restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr, int base) {
  // Usually `errno = 0` set by calling code.
  intmax_t i = strtomax(nptr, endptr, base);
  if (i > INTMAX_MAX - 1) {
    if (errno == ERANGE) {
      errno = 0;
    }
    return strtoumax(nptr, endptr, base);
  }
  if (i < 0) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    return 0;
  }
  return (uintmax_t) i;
}
```

`errno` complicates things.<sup>*1</sup>

---

**`argc == 0` possible**

Following code is then UB.

```
if (argc != 5) {
    ...
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s ...\n", argv[0]);
```

---

<sup>*1</sup>

`strto...()` functions are most clearly used if the calling code first performs `errno = 0;`

This `strtoumax_alt()`, with its two step of approach of `strtointmax()/strtouintmax()` like-wise works best if the caller first performs `errno = 0;`

Yet if we want to better handle cases where `strtoumax_alt()` is called with a non-zero `errno` and regular `strtoumax()` does not set `errno` with the given parameters, then consider *restoring* `errno` before the 2nd `strto...()` function.  So if the calling code is somehow accumulating errors in `errno`, this restoration will better support that.

```
uintmax_t strtoumax_alt(const char * restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr, int base) {
  int errno_original = errno;
  intmax_t i = strtomax(nptr, endptr, base);
  if (i > INTMAX_MAX - 1) {
    errno = errno_original;
    return strtoumax(nptr, endptr, base);
  }
  ...
```

I suppose now there may be a race condition if 2 threads execute `strtoumax_alt()`, yet often such threads roll their own copy of `errno`.

Messing with global objects for error indication is tricky.

How I wish C afforded a direct return value and error flag feature (without a `struct`).

Comment: Although if `argc == 0`, then `argv[0]` is still valid but it will be `NULL`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen True that `argv[0]` itself is OK, yet `%s` expect a matching pointer to a _string_.  With `argv[0] == NULL`,  `argv[0]` is not a pointer to a string.

Comment: I know, but` it allows you to write `argv[0] ? argv[0] : "mpfrtest"`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen [True, true](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDB2pA76yfw).

Answer (score 5):

## General Observations

The good, the call to `malloc()` is tested for success, the code is properly indented and there are symbolic constants rather than raw numbers in most cases. Symbols that coude be added are `EXPECTED_ARG_COUNT 5`.

The code is too tightly packed, it needs more vertical spacing. It is very difficult to read and follow. There should be blank lines in `orbit()` and `main()` to separate the logic blocks (actually in all the functions but it is most notable in `orbit()` and `main()`).

The code is not user friendly, it expects all input to be in a specific order. It would be easier for users if each expected argument was preceded by a flag (for example `--precision <precision value>`).

Since the code is generating Mandelbrots I'm not sure why it isn't tied to graphic output.

## Use the Compiler to Find Possible Issues in the Code

I always compile with these flags to find possible issues in the code `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

In this case the gcc compiler generates the following warning messages:

> main.c: In function 'progress':
> main.c:62:64: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
> void progress(size_t m) { fprintf(stderr, "computed iteration %zu\n", m); }
> main.c:62:43: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
> void progress(size_t m) { fprintf(stderr, "computed iteration %zu\n", m); }
> main.c:62:64: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
> void progress(size_t m) { fprintf(stderr, "computed iteration %zu\n", m); }
> main.c:62:43: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
> void progress(size_t m) { fprintf(stderr, "computed iteration %zu\n", m); }
> main.c: In function 'main':
> main.c:126:31: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
> printf("iterations = %zu\n", m);
> main.c:126:16: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
> printf("iterations = %zu\n", m);
> main.c:126:31: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
> printf("iterations = %zu\n", m);
> main.c:126:16: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
> printf("iterations = %zu\n", m);
> main.c:130:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
> printf("orbit[%0*zu] = %13.6e + %13.6ei\n", width, i, creal(result[i]),
>
> main.c:130:37: warning: format '%e' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'size_t' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]
>
> printf("orbit[%0*zu] = %13.6e + %13.6ei\n", width, i, creal(result[i]),
> %13.6I64d
> main.c:130:16: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
> printf("orbit[%0*zu] = %13.6e + %13.6ei\n", width, i, creal(result[i]),
>
> main.c:130:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
>
> printf("orbit[%0*zu] = %13.6e + %13.6ei\n", width, i, creal(result[i]),
> main.c:130:37: warning: format '%e' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'size_t' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]
> printf("orbit[%0*zu] = %13.6e + %13.6ei\n", width, i, creal(result[i]),
>
> %13.6I64d
>
> main.c:130:16: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
>
> printf("orbit[%0*zu] = %13.6e + %13.6ei\n", width, i, creal(result[i]),

## Don't Call `exit(int status)` From `main()`

Since the `main()` function is the entry point for the program there is no need to call the `exit()` function, all that is needed is to `return` with the program status.

**Example**
Instead of

```
        exit(-3);
```

the code should be

```
       return(-3);
```

### System Provided Exit Values

All of the `exit()` calls contain raw numbers, there are 2 system provided exit values in the C programming language (also the C++ programming language). These are [EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status). These values should be used instead of raw numbers since they are system defined and system dependent.

## Complexity

The function `main()` is too complex (does too much). As programs grow in size the use of `main()` should be limited to calling functions that parse the command line, calling functions that set up for processing, calling functions that execute the desired function of the program, and calling functions to clean up after the main portion of the program.

There is also a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

There are at least 3 possible functions in `main()`.

- Parse the command line
- Set up the variables for processing
- Call orbit()
- Output the results

Comment: That is strange, I do not get these errors when compiling on my machine _with_ `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (I use `-std=gnu17` though)

Comment: In fact, I do not get these errors when using `-std=iso9899:2017` either.

Comment: @schuelermine I didn't specify C17.

Comment: I see. Well I wrote the program in C17. What standard are you compiling with?

Comment: I don’t see why using `exit()` inside `main()` is problematic. As far as I can tell in terms of observable behaviour it’s equivalent to `return` there.

Comment: @schuelermine It does work, but it isn't necessary and `exit()` should only be used by functions that are not entry points to the program.